# Debug sql database scoped credentials failure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, error-log, sql-data-warehouse

I created a scoped credential in a Azure SQL Datawarehouse database to create an external table over some files in a Azure Data Lake Store.

When I try creating the external table I get the message.

> Msg 105061, Level 16, State 1, Line 35 Unable to find any valid
>   credential associated with the specified data source. Credential is
>   required to connect to Azure Data Lake Store.

How do I troubleshoot this? My AzureAD application has access to the storage. I use the same AD-application (with a different key) for my Azure Data Factory pipeline that stores the files in the Azure Data Lake Store.

I haven't found any commands that let you test your credentials and see what credentials the database tries to use or why it fails. Any ideas?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had missed adding my scoped credential when I created the external data source. So create the scoped credential first, then the external data source.

Comment: I'm confused as to the Identity - is that a Server Login, User or what?? This article states that CONTROL permission must be given - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

How did you handle this?

Comment: The scoped credential is a login the database uses to access other resources, for instance when you declare external tables. It's a login scoped to the database. The CONTROL permissions is needed by the database user creating the scoped credential in the database.